# How do I prevent the user from inserting or updating values for certain columns?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy as the ORM for my PostgreSQL database, I would like to add a constraint (or something similar) in my model definition that prevents a user from:

1) Inserting a value into a column they're not supposed to insert into (e.g. my auto-incrementing primary key or a date_modified that gets automatically set onupdate.)

2) Updating values in the same columns.

Basically - I would like inserts and/or updates to fail if they are attempting to touch specific columns.

**EDIT**

For clarification: I would like to declare this through my model (which inherit's from SQLAlchemy's Base).

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL supports [declarative column security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) (as well as row security)

Use this template:

```
GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | REFERENCES } ( column_name [, ...] )
    [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] ( column_name [, ...] ) }
    ON [ TABLE ] table_name [, ...]
    TO role_specification [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

Example:

```
GRANT INSERT (colA, colB) ON TABLE foo TO michi;
```

Comment: I would like to declare this through SQLAlchemy rather than PostgresQL using my model (that uses SQLAlchemy's Base).

Comment: @Michi: This is DB administration, not DB data structure. It's not SQLAlchemy's domain. It's also not supported by every SQL database. (In a high-security environment, I'd have roles with fine-grained grants, and would assign roles to users.) On SQLAlchemy level, you can try to use [events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html) to _additionally_ check access rights.

Comment: You could include the required grants as [custom DDL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/ddl.html) along with your models.

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way I could think of doing this would be to use:

```
final int (name) = x;
```

This way the value can't be changed while running.